# Apple keyboard in openbox

Tags: fedora, gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome3, openbox

I just upgraded from Fedora 15 to 16.

I'm using Openbox as an alternative to Gnome 3. The problem is that I cannot find a way of using the multimedia keys properly in Openbox. Changing the keyboard layout and other (I think) Gnome-based keyboard shortcuts do not work as well, while in Gnome all they keyboard settings work perfectly.

Before (in Fedora 15) I was '*tricking*' Openbox by running and killing gnome's keyboard settings at startup.

```
timeout -sHUP 1s gnome-control-center region
```

This seemed to run some kind of service in the background that was letting me use all the keys in the keyboard and gnome-specific short cuts in Openbox.

I know that I can set up some key bindings in Openbox (*rc.xml*), the thing is that there are some keys (F13 to F18) in Apple's keyboard that are really useful when setting special. These special keys (and keyboard-layout-changing short cuts) can be seen in Gnome but cannot be seen by Openbox.

Any clue on what kind of service Gnome is running that Openbox is not that it is able to 'see' all the keys in the Apple keyboard?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Could you write your solution as an answer? So It will not be listed as an unanswered question.

Comment: I don't know if you've tried yet but running xev and pressing the relevant buttons should give you codes to use in rc.xml

Comment: I don't have an apple keyboard around at the moment but I'll check it out when I do and report. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found that the responsible of this is the gnome-settings-daemon.

```
/usr/libexec/gnome-settings-daemon
```